# Bootstrap 5 Center image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I tried centering an image horizontally my giving the parent div the class `justify-content-center` as well as `text-center`.

This worked for any text, however the image remains to the left, rather than centered. How do I fix this?

```css
.thumbnail {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}



.thumbnail > img {
    max-height: 10em;
    max-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
  <div class="col col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
    <a href="/characters/pine">
      <div class="thumbnail align-text-bottom text-center">
        <img class="center-block" src="https://media.gettyimages.com/id/157615990/photo/lasagna.jpg?s=612x612&w=gi&k=20&c=ue-VP7TbzbfT-KUHdhUz5T9CPBGteCiTESjiqA8CVHw=">
      </div>
      <div>Pineapple Lasagna Coleslaw</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Debug, the reason why its not center because ```.thumbnail```, is has height and width which is forcing image to be stay in left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the thumbnail width itself is the exact width of the image, so it's centered but not as wide as you want it to be. Change the width of the thumbnail to 100% so it inherits the width of its parents and the image will center properly.

```css
.thumbnail {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10em;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}



.thumbnail > img {
    max-height: 10em;
    max-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
  <div class="col col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
    <a href="/characters/pine">
      <div class="thumbnail align-text-bottom text-center">
        <img class="center-block" src="https://media.gettyimages.com/id/157615990/photo/lasagna.jpg?s=612x612&w=gi&k=20&c=ue-VP7TbzbfT-KUHdhUz5T9CPBGteCiTESjiqA8CVHw=">
      </div>
      <div>Pineapple Lasagna Coleslaw</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what an easy fix! thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

The image is positioned correctly but the div with the class `.thumbnail` is positioned to the left of the parent anchor. Just add `mx-auto` to this div to center it.

```css
.thumbnail {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.thumbnail > img {
    max-height: 10em;
    max-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
  <div class="col col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
    <a href="/characters/pine">
      <div class="thumbnail align-text-bottom text-center mx-auto"><!-- added mx-auto to this -->
        <img class="center-block" src="https://media.gettyimages.com/id/157615990/photo/lasagna.jpg?s=612x612&w=gi&k=20&c=ue-VP7TbzbfT-KUHdhUz5T9CPBGteCiTESjiqA8CVHw=">
      </div>
      <div>Pineapple Lasagna Coleslaw</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```